# How to modify the login panel

Tags: templating, control-panel, admin, login

how can i modify the login html?
I specifically want to add an image below the title.

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can add a logo to the login page by uploading one to Settings → General **Login Page Logo**.

If you need further tweaking, you could use the [Control Panel CSS](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-css) plugin.

I wouldn't recommend modifying Craft's templates.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding a module that is supposed to act as a sitemodule with different functions I use over most of my projects.

Inside that module you register an asset bundle that ultimately adds a CSS stylesheet to the controlpanel.

This way you can alter the look of the loginpage without tampering with any of Crafts innards. As can be seen from the screenshot, I have hidden the title and added another background image.

Update: To get started, head over to [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io) and enter the required fields. E.g. name it `Simple Site Module`. You don't need to select any of the lightswitches if you don't know what they do. Then hit "Build my module" and it will download an example module. You put that folder into "modules" inside your Craft 3 project. Then you add the contents from `config/app.php`(inside the new module folder) into your projects `config/app.php`.

Now with that module enabled (hit reload in your project to ensure you dont have any errors) you can put your custom css styles into `assetbundles/simplesitemodule/dist/css/SimpleSiteModule.css`.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/MisterMike/e8f6cd3d8cfadb84c69c6979ca74d401) with what could be in that CSS file.

[image: example login page modified with custom css via a Craft CMS (Yii) module]

Comment: This answer would be significantly more helpful if you shared the code.

Comment: I have updated my answer @InanisAtheos. I don't think I should post the entire code of a module here, but with that information you are good to go and experiment. You can find the background image I used at this location in your project: `/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/installer/src/images/installer-bg.png`